# Add key and value from other array of hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have two array of hashes .Both have similar values in them but i want to create new key in the hash that will have the some values of second array of hash.

First Array:

```
[
    { area_code => 93,   name => 'Afghanistan',    code => 'AF', slno => 4554 },
    { area_code => 1684, name => 'American Samoa', code => 'AS', slno => 4557 },
];
```

Second Array:

```
[
    { city => "Berat",  country => "AS", id => 134368 },
    { city => "Durres", country => "AS", id => 138466 },
    { city => "Kabul",  country => "AF", id => 142462 },
];
```

Now in the first hash i have key **code** whose value is similar to the second hash key **country** .So i want to add a new key in the second array of hash which will be **country_name**.And the **country_name** value will be the value of first array of hash **name**.

So how can we do this please help me in this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $a1 = [
    { area_code => 93,   code => "AF", name => "Afghanistan",    slno => 4554 },
    { area_code => 1684, code => "AS", name => "American Samoa", slno => 4557 },
];

my $a2 = [
    { city => "Berat",  country => "AS", id => 134368 },
    { city => "Durres", country => "AS", id => 138466 },
    { city => "Kabul",  country => "AF", id => 142462 },
];

my %h = map { $_->{code} => $_ } @$a1;
for my $v (@$a2) {
    $v->{country_name} = $h{ $v->{country} }{name};
}
```

Comment: Please comment when down voting as reason is not obvious.

Comment: Though I didn't downvote, one potential downside I see is the copying of entire `@$a1` which we can limit to `$_->{code} => $_->{name}` other wise it was clear to me so you have my upvote.

Comment: @jaypal yes, that could be the reason.

Answer (score 3):

This is a similar idea to @mpapec's, but, I think, a little cleaner.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array1 = (
   { area_code => 93,   name => 'Afghanistan',    code => 'AF', slno => 4554 },
   { area_code => 1684, name => 'American Samoa', code => 'AS', slno => 4557 },
);

my @array2 = (
   { country => 'AS', city => 'Berat',  id => 134368 },
   { country => 'AS', city => 'Durres', id => 138466 },
   { country => 'AF', city => 'Kabul',  id => 142462 },
);

{
   my %names = map { $_->{code} => $_->{name} } @array1;
   $_->{country_name} = $names{ $_->{country} } for @array2;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \@array2;
```

**output**

```
[
  {
    country      => 'AS',
    city         => 'Berat',
    id           => 134368,
    country_name => 'American Samoa',
  },
  {
    country      => 'AS',
    city         => 'Durres',
    id           => 138466,
    country_name => 'American Samoa',
  },
  {
    country      => 'AF',
    city         => 'Kabul',
    id           => 142462,
    country_name => 'Afghanistan',
  },
]
```